# Convert array values to int in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have array named data in that i have sub array as place_id,when I print place_id from data array as

```
dd($data['place_id'])
```

It gives me result as

```
 array:1 [
   0 => "7"
   1 => "3"
 ]
```

I want values to be of type int as follows:

```
array:1 [
       0 => 7
       1 => 3
     ]
```

How will I get this result  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intval()` with `array_map()`:

```php
$data['place_id'] = array_map('intval', $data['place_id']);
```

Comment: you should quote the intval function

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of options:

1.Using [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $data[$k] = intval($v);
    }

    dd($data);
```

**Result:**

```
array:2 [
  0 => 7
  1 => 3
]
```

2.Using [array_map()](https://www.php.net/array_map) which is also for loop at the end:

```
 $data['place_id'] = array_map('intval', $data['place_id']);
 dd($data);
```

**Result:**

```
array:2 [
  0 => 7
  1 => 3
]
```